# Change a linked version of boost in an already compiled executable

Tags: c++, boost, linker

I have a compiled program, on older unix servers it worked just fine, on new servers however i get this error:

> error while loading shared libraries: libboost reerror while loading shared libraries: libboost_reex.so.2

It is important to mention i am not the owner of the server so i cant make any changes requiring root permission.

I have used the ldd command for both files on the servers and received this results:
on the older server:

```
ldd conglfinder 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff427fd000)
    libnsl.so.1 => /lib64/libnsl.so.1 (0x0000003d64400000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000003d5d800000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x0000003d5d000000)
    libboost_regex.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libboost_regex.so.2 (0x00002ba6c486d000)
    libboost_filesystem.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libboost_filesystem.so.2 (0x00002ba6c4b19000)
    libbiu-bio-clone.so => not found
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x0000003d62400000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x0000003d5cc00000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003d5c800000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x0000003d62000000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003d5c400000)
    libicui18n.so.36 => /usr/lib64/libicui18n.so.36 (0x00002ba6c4d2b000)
    libicuuc.so.36 => /usr/lib64/libicuuc.so.36 (0x00002ba6c506f000)
    libicudata.so.36 => /usr/lib64/libicudata.so.36 (0x00002ba6c53a5000)
```

and on the new server:

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff3c55c000)
libnsl.so.1 => /lib64/libnsl.so.1 (0x0000003648600000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x000000363b200000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x000000363b600000)
libboost_regex.so.2 => not found
libboost_filesystem.so.2 => not found
libbiu-bio-clone.so => not found
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x000000363fa00000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x000000363be00000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x000000363ae00000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x000000363ea00000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000000363aa00000)
```

Is there a way to fix this linking error without recompiling the code?

**Updates:**

I have got my hands on the source files and recompiled it on the new Unix server and after compilation tried to run the program, but still gating the same error.
At this point the ldd command on the new server returns this information:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffe97ff000)
libnsl.so.1 => /lib64/libnsl.so.1 (0x0000003648600000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x000000363b200000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x000000363b600000)
libboost_regex.so.5 => /usr/lib64/libboost_regex.so.5 (0x00007f80751e7000)
libboost_filesystem.so.5 => /usr/lib64/libboost_filesystem.so.5 (0x00007f8074fd2000)
libbiu-bio-clone.so => not found
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x000000363fa00000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x000000363be00000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x000000363ae00000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x000000363ea00000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000000363aa00000)
libicuuc.so.42 => /usr/lib64/libicuuc.so.42 (0x0000003646600000)
libicui18n.so.42 => /usr/lib64/libicui18n.so.42 (0x0000003647800000)
libboost_system.so.5 => /usr/lib64/libboost_system.so.5 (0x00007f8074dcc000)
libicudata.so.42 => /usr/lib64/libicudata.so.42 (0x0000003649e00000)
```

To answer the questions in the comments:

The new server does not contain the: libboost_regex.so.2 in its boost libraries, and i cant add them there.

As can be seen in the ldd log Boos is installed on the new server.

**Updates2:**
I have had the missing library to another place on my directories and repatched
and now i get this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_regex.so.2, needed by ../BaseLib/libbiu-bio-clone
.so, may conflict with libboost_regex.so.5
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libicui18n.so.36, needed by /home/ls/ravid/cluster_Try/lib
boost_regex.so.2, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libicuuc.so.36, needed by /home/ls/ravid/cluster_Try/libbo
ost_regex.so.2, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/ls/ravid/cluster_Try/libboost_regex.so.2: undefined reference to `u_isspac
e_3_6'
/home/ls/ravid/cluster_Try/libboost_regex.so.2: undefined reference to `u_tolowe
r_3_6'
/home/ls/ravid/cluster_Try/libboost_regex.so.2: undefined reference to `u_isblan
k_3_6'
/home/ls/ravid/cluster_Try/libboost_regex.so.2: undefined reference to `icu_3_6:
:Collator::createInstance(icu_3_6::Locale const&, UErrorCode&)'
/home/ls/ravid/cluster_Try/libboost_regex.so.2: undefined reference to `icu_3_6:
:Locale::~Locale()'
/home/ls/ravid/cluster_Try/libboost_regex.so.2: undefined reference to `icu_3_6:
:Locale::Locale(icu_3_6::Locale const&)'
/home/ls/ravid/cluster_Try/libboost_regex.so.2: undefined reference to `u_charFr
omName_3_6'
/home/ls/ravid/cluster_Try/libboost_regex.so.2: undefined reference to `u_charTy
pe_3_6'
/home/ls/ravid/cluster_Try/libboost_regex.so.2: undefined reference to `icu_3_6:
:Locale::Locale()'
/home/ls/ravid/cluster_Try/libboost_regex.so.2: undefined reference to `u_digit_
3_6'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [conglfinder] Error 1
```

How should i proceed?

Comment: Try setting up the boost regex library (`libboost_regex.so.2`) on the new machine, somewhere in your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. You can see the libraries it can't find, and you can see where it found them on the old machine.

Comment: Boost *is* installed on the "new" server?

Comment: Note that the title of the question, as it's phrased now, is a fool's errand. If your software is linked against a particular version of Boost, trying to modify the resulting binary to coax it into running against some other version will not work reliably. In general, Boost does not guarantee ABI backward compatibility, so this is likely to be rife with problems. However, nothing should prevent you from installing the same Boost library version on the new server, allowing your existing application to run.

Comment: @Useless the server doesn't contain this library and i cant add any libraries to the boost or any other root requiring permission, you can see in the new log what it does contain.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg  the server does in fact has boost install on it as you can see in the log.

Comment: @JasonR After reading you'r comment i did recompiled it but still getting the same error, suggestions?

Comment: Copy the missing library to somewhere on the server you _can_ put it, and then run your binary with a modified LD_LIBRARY_PATH. If you can't administer your dependencies properly on your servers, try statically linking boost instead.

Comment: Thank you @Useless, can you plsease alaborate on how to modify my LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Comment: Just search for it, and ask a new question about that if you need to. It's an environment variable, and this is basic shell stuff.

Comment: @Useless please view the latest update, suggestions?

Comment: You've now somehow compiled against a different version of boost than you're finding at runtime (note the `.so.2` vs `.so.5`). Find the libraries you _compiled and linked_ with, and put them somewhere you can use them at runtime.